# Firebase function return

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function to get the link of the images. I want to show the images when i click the marker along with the additional details. The problem is the function returns undefined.

Table Structure:

Report Files //table name

-M27OTpU_Be6D8gPQujA //id

1583910088597: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lto"

1583910088685: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lto"

```
  //this is where i all the function
  contentString = '<div class="info-window-content">' + 
 ret(ids) + '</div>';

//returns the url of the images. I want show it when i click the marker
function ret(ids) {
var pic;
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Report Files/" 
          + ids)
rootRef.once('value').then(function(childs) {
childs.forEach(function (child) {
pic += '<img src="' + child.val() + '" style="display: 
block;width:200px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;height="200">';
return pic;
    });
    });
      }
```

Comment: add ur database

Comment: if you do `pic += '<img src="' + child.val() + '" style="display: 
block;width:200px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;height="200">';console.log(pic);` what do you get?

Comment: <img src=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lto style="display: block;width:200px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;height="200"> I get the url of the image

Comment: did you try the answer?

Comment: I did it returns [object Promise]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function ret(ids) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
var pic;
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Report Files/" + ids)
rootRef.once('value').then(function(childs) {
childs.forEach(function (child) {
pic += '<img src="' + child.val() + '" style="display: 
block;width:200px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;height="200">';
resolve(pic);
         });
       });
     });
    }
```

Return a `promise` from the function `ret`, use `resolve(pic)` to return the value of `pic` when the `promise` is finished. Then to get the value of `pic`, you can do the following:

```
  contentString = '<div class="info-window-content">' + 
 ret(ids).then((result)=>{result}) + '</div>';
```

The `then()` method, takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

Check here for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: it returns [ object Promise]

Comment: you need to add `ret(ids).then((result)=>{result})` before creating the `<div>` then what you retrieve the data and assign it to a variable, you can use that variable inside `contentString`